# Why would I get an exception on a working server only once its running on host domain?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, networking, network-programming, server-side

I have a client/server program that runs great on many private machines. However, once I install the server on a host domain of Amazon Lightsail, Windows Server 2016, I get an exception.

I am using UDP socket and trying to bind with the static IP I have but I am getting this exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address is not valid in its context
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at AP_Server_Side.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I have tried many different ports as well as zero.

My code:

```
  Socket _reciveSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
  IPAddress _localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("52.56.192.252");
  IPEndPoint _localip = new IPEndPoint(_localAddress, 0);
  Console.WriteLine("local Address : " + _localip.ToString());
  IPEndPoint _newend = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
  EndPoint _escoler = (EndPoint)_newend;

    byte[] _bufferrecived = new byte[1024];
    byte[] _sendBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int _recivefrom;
    string _msgRecived = string.Empty;
    int _userint = 1;
        try
        {

                _reciveSocket.Bind(_localip);
```

I doubt the problem is in the code because as I said the server has been tested and runs great on more than one machine.

I'm guessing its something with Windows or server setting, I turned firewall off and tried inbound all UDP reference.

Comment: Where did you get "52.56.192.252" from? My guess is that is a valid IP address on your private machine but not in the hosted environment. You can only bind to an address that is assigned to your network interface. Perhaps you should bind to `IPAddress.Any` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30890249/2791540))

Comment: i got the ip as a static ip from lightsail, i need a static ip to listen to so i can give a static address to clients, thats the all reason for this server. i will have a look now on the attached link. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with the environment your deploying too. From the sound of it lightsail is meant for simple deployments for apps that just listen for HTTP traffic (TCP). And my best guess is that 52.56.192.252 address. Any or localhost 127.0.0.1 will probably work better. Unfortunately you can't bind to addresses willy nilly, and it depends on you network interface's IP range.

It could also be related to the network settings for your particular lightsail instance.
You might want to check this out:
[Lightsail ports and firewalls](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail)

Also this might be of use in your investigations.
[Investigating lightsail port information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lightsail/2016-11-28/api-reference/API_InstancePortInfo.html)

Also I would recommend learning more about networking and IP addresses before going and doing this kind of low-level socket programming!

Comment: Not meant as a comment on your code, my apologies if I offended! As someone who has also gone through this learning phase I know it's easy to make something work, but often you get caught out by details and gaps in understanding. Annoyingly with networking, there are a lot of layers, so in order to use one effectively it helps to know the others. 
I think the issue is that you can't bind to that IP, or that you can't open a UDP port because of privleges or the lightsail in env is somehow locked down.
I hope AWS support is more helpful.